# Determine if an app is running in the foreground when a notification is received on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking, foreground

I would like to find a way to see what app is running in foreground or if the home screen is displayed when a local notification from my app show up. For example i want to have different actions if there is in homescreen or in someone else app.
I tried to use processed and pid but the pid is generated hen the app starts and not the last time the app is used.
Any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 65):

As described in the [push notification documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/Introduction.html) you can read [`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationState) when you receive the notification to determine whether your app is in foreground, inactive (it's visible but a dialog like the WiFi chooser is in front) or in background.

Comment: i want to know if anither app is running in foreground like camera or ipod or notes

Comment: So, what part of my answer do you have trouble with? If you read `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]` it tells you whether your app is foreground or not.

Comment: Yes. this is for my app. how I would now exactly what app was before mine?IF was Camera for example or an appstore app?

Comment: There is no way to get this information. You only know whether your app is in foreground or not.

Answer (score 21):

Just to have a copy-paste code available for others:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
    //App is in foreground. Act on it.
}
```

Comment: p1us 0ne for the copy paste

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 5 version:**

```
import UIKit
let isForeground = UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting you need `import UIKit` since it's not obvious where the identifier `UIApplication` comes from.